# How can I wire my new wall sconce?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, multiway-switch

EDITS: added photos

I had a hallway with a wall sconce (which I'll call sconce 1), a ceiling light, and a switch on each end that controlled both. I had an electrician put wiring in for a second sconce in between sconce 1 and ceiling light, but didn't have him actually install the new fixture. The wiring for sconce 2 was straightforward and I connected it myself - ground to ground, white to white, black to black, as shown here.

[image]

Here's how my fixtures and switches are arranged. I did not actually test it at this point, though should have.
[image]

Then I went to replace the fixture on sconce 1 so that it would match sconce 2, the new one. The problem is, there are a bunch of new wires on sconce 1 now since he connected sconce 2 via sconce 1. And I didn't pay enough attention when I was disconnecting sconce 1 (rookie mistake). Now I'm unsure how to reconnect sconce 1 correctly.

Here's a diagram of what the wires look like on sconce 1 and what I tried connecting:

[image]

And a photo of the spot for sconce 1. You can see three black wires, a ground, and three white, one of which is marked with black tape.
[image]

The result of the wiring shown in the diagram is that both sconces work, but the ceiling light does not.

I then tried this idea, which resulted in sconce 1 and the ceiling light working, but not sconce 2.
[image]

Any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: The drawings are good, but actual pictures of the switch and the wiring behind each of the sconces would be even better. Label the pics to match up with the labels in your drawings.

Comment: Thanks, I added photos. Hope that helps.